# Set Ninject property to private

Tags: c#, .net, ninject, repository-pattern

I have a project using Ninject. I create an Interface and implement it in another class. Add the below code to register the service

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IArticleContent>().To<ArticleService>().InRequestScope();
}
```

Create a web page and write the following code

```
[Inject]
public IArticleContent _ArticleContentService { get; set; }
```

Write further code to get the data bound to a control and **all works**.

I then change the above public declaration to private

```
[Inject]
private IArticleContent _ArticleContentService { get; set; }
```

And get

*Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

After some research i added

```
new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings() { InjectNonPublic = true });
```

to the `NinjectWebCommon` class under the Start method (also tried with `RegisterServices` method) but same error. So after further research it either seems i need to do this another way (i.e. within a constructor of my service class) or i need the above code somewhere else.

Could anyone advise how to use a property with Ninject when it set private or the "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting `InjectNonPublic` to `true`, you also need to set `InjectParentPrivateProperties` to `true`:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings
{
    InjectNonPublic = true,
    InjectParentPrivateProperties = true
});
```

The reason is the page class itself is in fact used as a parent to a class generated from the corresponding `aspx` file at runtime.